# Trigger headerBasket headerCartUpdate

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I created a script that opens the minicart. Now adding product is made using JS/Ajax and I don't refresh the page. Now the problem is the Basket count is not being updated when I add to cart. Is there a way to manually triggers the `headerCartUpdate` function from Magento_Theme headerBasket.js?

So basically I want to call it after the `ajaxSubmit` of the catalog-add-to-cart.js

Answer (score 0):

Magento fires 2 events in `ajaxSubmit` method 
event `catalogCategoryAddToCartRedirect` in code `$('body').trigger('catalogCategoryAddToCartRedirect', eventData);` fired if you set redirect to cart after add product configuration to true

The other one is `contentUpdated` in code `$(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentUpdated')` if minicart is enabled.

You can subscribe to anyone based on your approach and execute your method.

You will need to add this code in

> app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(['jquery'], function($){
    $("body").on("contentUpdated", function(event){
        // here; you can run any logic on event then run your method
    });
});
</script>
```